# Does consumer recover after Kafka cluster was down for a long time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I start Kafka consumer on server start up. What happens to the consumer if Kafka cluster goes down for a long time (couple of hours)? Will it receive messages after Kafka is up again?

Answer (score 0):

It ultimately depends on how you handle connection exceptions in the client.

If you have a Circuit Breaker type logic of retry+fail after a few times, then the consume loop would stop. Otherwise, if you blindly do a while(true) loop, then the consumer would keep trying to read messages, and be logging errors on each request (heartbeat, fetch, or poll)

Answer (score 0):

As the Kafka protocol works, they are always the clients (consumers in this case) to start communication with the cluster in a request/reply fashion.
It means that if the cluster goes down, the consumer will get this status only on its next request (maybe a metadata request or a fetch request). There is no push mechanism from brokers to clients to say them that the cluster came back working properly. So it depends on the logic of your consumer and how many times it polls for getting messages; as already mentioned by @cricket_007, it will log errors.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka stores messages and current offset values in disk for time which is defined in broker config as log.retention (default is 168 hours). So during down time your consumers will get "Broker may not be available" error each time they are trying to poll. When kafka is up, if down time is less than log.retention time, then your consumers will continue to receive and consume messages without any loss.